# One author, multiple affiliations

Tags: ieeetran

Using IEEEtran I want to have one author with two affiliations.

This is the code:

```
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Name Surname}


\IEEEauthorblockA{Faculty of Something\\
University of Somewhere\\
Email: l.ipsum@tex.org}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockA{Faculty of Something and\\Something Else\\
University of Some Other Place\\
Email: i.lorem@stack.org}
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

I want the name to be centered on top and the two affiliations bellow, in the same row equally centered left and right.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you update your [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to make it compilable? It should begin with ``\documentclass{...}`` and end with ``\end{document}``.

Answer (score 2):

The author section is implemented as a tabular, albeit with special formatting.  You can put a tabular inside another tabular.

You could even add a third column just for the "and."

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\title{Much Ado about Nothing}
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\begin{tabular}{cc}
Faculty of Something & and Something Else\\
University of Somewhere & University of Some Other Place\\
Email: l.ipsum@tex.org & Email: i.lorem@stack.org
\end{tabular}}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```